# Small Z axis step: Repetier-Firmware

Tags: z-axis, stepper-driver

Z axis length for my printer equals 120 mm. When I manually pass this length, from display controller menu, it's about few millimeters. Then I set the resolution (ZAXIS_STEPS_PER_MM) at [1600 steps per mm](http://prusaprinters.org/calculator/). And nothing changed, step still very small.

I use Repetier-Firmware, Arduino Mega+RAMPS 1.4, standard Nema 17 steppers and Prusa i3 like cartesian printer.

This is hardware or software problem? I checked the steppers, they're fine.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by [change EEPROM value to "2"](https://www.repetier.com/documentation/repetier-firmware/rf-installation/) in Configuration.h:

```
#define EEPROM_MODE 2
```

Now ZAXIS_STEPS_PER_MM value load from firmware, not EEPROM.

```
#define EEPROM_MODE 0
```

— does not result in my case.